# Audio Not Play After Refresh Page

Tags: html, jquery, audio, media

The audio play inconsistently. The html page able to play the sound but once the reload button from Chrome is clicked, the error appear as follow:

**Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first**

If open the page from another page, the sound still able to play. The issue is only when Refresh button is clicked.
Audio tag as shown below:

````
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source id="source" src="../cgi-bin/media/EmergencyAlert.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>```
````

Comment: Not enough code to recreate your problem... I suspect there is a `.play();` in your Javascript that is NOT inside a click handler function.